# Catching incoming couchdb documents

Tags: couchdb, view

I would like to be aware of every time a document is sent to couch so that I can process that document via an external service.

I know that views are updated automatically, is there some way to hook into that process? Could I define logic in the view that would make http requests to external services? Possibly this external service would be a couch app.

I'm basically looking for some kind of trigger, initiated by a document being stored in couch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the [changes feed](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/changes.html) for this, which will give you a way to monitor all database writes. (including document creation)

To be clear, this gives you a hook to do some processing *after* it has already been added to your database, so you won't be able to preprocess the document in this fashion. (depending on your requirements, you can use a [validation handler](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) or an [update handler](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions) for that)

Comment: Thanks. I want to process the document after it has been added to the CouchDB (the data will be validated and sent to a second database, the initial one will be raw surveys). This methods still looks like I'm going to have to 'poll' the database (not sure if that is the right term...). Is there any way around that?

Comment: There are some [more docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/changes.html#changes) around this. Polling is just one option, you can also do long-polling, continuous streaming and use EventSource.

Comment: Thanks. The continuous or event source streams seem to be what I'm looking for. With continous streaming could you leave the connection open indefinitely?

Comment: Yeah, basically. Provided the server doesn't reboot or you lose your connection or something. (not that those things happen spontaneously)